# Excel VBA mail merge with conditions

Tags: excel, vba

I am really looking forward to get some help because I am trying for so long now...

I want to get a button in excel that starts a word mailmerge and save every letter as a single document. I already found a code, that is doing this fine.

Now comes the problem: I need excel to take different word templates depending on the number in column A (Column A is called Anz). So if column A = 0 there wont be any mail merge (I already managed this by adding "where (Anz>0) to the sql statement.

If column A = 1 excel shall take sb1.docx as the proper mail merge template.
If column A = 2 it shall take sb2.docx and so on.
The numbers go from 0 to 6.

I have no idea how to to this :(

My code so far (that is working but only for the sb1.docx).

```html
Sub RunMerge()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StrMMSrc As String, StrMMDoc As String, StrMMPath As String, StrName As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Const StrNoChr As String = """*/\:?|"
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document
wdApp.Visible = False
wdApp.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone
StrMMSrc = ThisWorkbook.FullName
StrMMPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
StrMMDoc = StrMMPath & "sb1.docx"
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(Filename:=StrMMDoc, AddToRecentFiles:=False, ReadOnly:=True, Visible:=False)
With wdDoc
  With .MailMerge
    .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
    .OpenDataSource Name:=StrMMSrc, ReadOnly:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
      LinkToSource:=False, Connection:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;" & _
      "Data Source=StrMMSrc;Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";", _
      SQLStatement:="SELECT * FROM `Sheet1$` where (Anz>0)"
    For i = 1 To .DataSource.RecordCount
      .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
      .SuppressBlankLines = True
      With .DataSource
        .FirstRecord = i
        .LastRecord = i
        .ActiveRecord = i
        If Trim(.DataFields("ID")) = "" Then Exit For
        StrName = .DataFields("ID")
      End With
      .Execute Pause:=False
      For j = 1 To Len(StrNoChr)
        StrName = Replace(StrName, Mid(StrNoChr, j, 1), "_")
      Next
      StrName = Trim(StrName)
      With wdApp.ActiveDocument
        .SaveAs Filename:=StrMMPath & StrName & ".docx", FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddToRecentFiles:=False
        ' and/or:
        '.SaveAs Filename:=StrMMPath & StrName & ".pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF, AddToRecentFiles:=False
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
      End With
    Next i
    .MainDocumentType = wdNotAMergeDocument
  End With
  .Close SaveChanges:=False
End With
wdApp.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsAll
wdApp.Quit
Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not create 7 different tables and 7 different mail merges (column A numbers from 0 to 6)? **Or** filter your table by one of the column A numbers and run your code 7 times!

Comment: Because I want my colleagues to use this and they are not able to do anything else than press a button "create mail merge documents"....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

Requirements:
- Each Anz number has it's corresponding template
- The excel spreadsheet has a column called "Anz"
- You have to add the Microsoft Word object library to VBA IDE references

Implementation:
1) Copy and paste the code inside a vba module
2) Customize the code (seek for >>>> customize this <<<<)

Updates:
1) Adjusted the queryString
2) Updated the OpenDataSource code to be more clear
3) Added a fileCounter

Code:

```
' First you have to configure the settings in each template so the word template filters the data already
' Also add a reference in Excel / VBA IDE to: Microsoft Word [Version] Object Library
Public Sub RunMergeDifferentWordTemplates()

    ' Declare objects
    Dim wordApp As Word.Application
    Dim wordTemplate As Word.Document
    Dim wordMergedDoc As Word.MailMerge

    ' Declare other variables
    Dim sourceBookPath As String
    Dim sheetSourceName As String
    Dim excelColumnFilter As String
    Dim queryString As String
    Dim baseQueryString As String

    Dim wordTemplateDirectory As String
    Dim wordTemplateFileName As String
    Dim wordTemplateFullPath As String
    Dim wordOutputDirectory As String
    Dim wordOutputFileName As String
    Dim wordOutputFullPath As String

    Dim idListValues As Variant ' Array
    Dim idValue As Integer
    Dim idCounter As Integer
    Dim recordCounter As Integer
    Dim fileCounter As Integer

    ' >>>>> Customize this <<<<<<

    ' This would be better to hold it in an Excel structured table
    ' I'm not including 0 as it's not needed (these would correspon to the anz values).
    idListValues = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

    ' Excel source settings:
    sourceBookPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    sheetSourceName = "Sheet1" ' The sheet where the data of the mail merge is located
    excelColumnFilter = "Anz" ' The column we use to filter the mail merge data
    baseQueryString = "SELECT * FROM `" & sheetSourceName & "$` where `" & excelColumnFilter & "` = [columFilterValue] order by `" & excelColumnFilter & "` ASC" ' Would be a better practice to use an Excel structured table: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c

    ' Word settings:
    wordTemplateDirectory = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" ' Include slash at the end
    wordTemplateFileName = "sb[columFilterValue].docx" ' Include in the string [columFilterValue] where you want it to be replaced (remember that you have one template for each number)
    wordOutputDirectory = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" ' Include slash at the end
    wordOutputFileName = "MailMergeDifferent[columFilterValue]_[Record]" ' Leave the [columFilterValue] and [Record] tags inside the path to identify each document. We'll replace it ahead, dynamically

    ' Initialize word object
    Set wordApp = New Word.Application
    wordApp.Visible = True
    wordApp.DisplayAlerts = wdAlertsNone

    ' Loop through each idValue in idListValues
    For idCounter = 0 To UBound(idListValues)

        ' Process each word template
        idValue = idListValues(idCounter)
        queryString = Replace(baseQueryString, "[columFilterValue]", idValue)
        wordTemplateFullPath = wordTemplateDirectory & Replace(wordTemplateFileName, "[columFilterValue]", idValue)

        Set wordTemplate = wordApp.Documents.Open(wordTemplateFullPath)

        Set wordMergedDoc = wordTemplate.MailMerge

        ' Process the template's mail merge
        With wordMergedDoc

            .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters

            .OpenDataSource _
                Name:=sourceBookPath, _
                ReadOnly:=True, _
                Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
                Revert:=False, _
                AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
                LinkToSource:=False, _
                Connection:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;User ID=Admin;" & _
                    "Data Source=" & sourceBookPath & ";Mode=Read;Extended Properties=""HDR=YES;IMEX=1"";", _
                SQLStatement:=queryString

            .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument

            .SuppressBlankLines = True

            ' Each anz have matching records inside the excel worksheet (generate a word file for each one)
            For recordCounter = 1 To .DataSource.RecordCount

                ' Select each record
                With .DataSource

                    .FirstRecord = wordMergedDoc.DataSource.ActiveRecord
                    .LastRecord = wordMergedDoc.DataSource.ActiveRecord

                End With
                .Execute Pause:=False

                ' Add the columnFilterValue and the record identifier to the word file name
                ' Replace the columnFilterValue and the Record tags
                wordOutputFullPath = wordOutputDirectory & Replace(Replace(wordOutputFileName, "[columFilterValue]", idValue), "[Record]", recordCounter)

                ' Save and close the resulting document
                wordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 Filename:=wordOutputFullPath, FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddToRecentFiles:=False
                wordApp.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 Filename:=wordOutputFullPath, FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF, AddToRecentFiles:=False
                wordApp.ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=False

                .DataSource.ActiveRecord = wdNextRecord

                ' Count files generated
                fileCounter = fileCounter + 1


            Next recordCounter

        End With


        ' Close word template without saving
        wordTemplate.Close False

    Next idCounter

    ' Clean up word objects
    wordApp.Visible = False
    Set wordApp = Nothing

    ' Alert process finished
    MsgBox fileCounter & " files generated"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! It is working now besides one problem: I get asked if I want save changes in sb1.docx and so on for every generated document :(

Comment: I just found out that the problem only occurs with the original sb1.docx - sb6.docx files. If I take the dummy files (they are much smaller) the problem is not occuring...

Comment: This line: wordTemplate.Close False is supposed to close the template without saving it. Can you debug the macro step by step and see where it is asking you to save the files? https://bettersolutions.com/vba/debugging/step-through-code.htm

Comment: That is between     wordTemplate.Close False and

    Next idCounter.

Comment: Is it possibly arguing with any addins or macros from my firm? and if yes, how can I manage to auto-close this msg-boxes?

Comment: Maybe if you add Application.SendKeys "N" after the line wordTemplate.Close False. try it and let me know.

Comment: Why is the word template open at all? Cant we tell them to not open sb1.docx - sb7-docx?

Comment: Ok, I think that was it ;D  I just changed    wordApp.Visible = True into    wordApp.Visible = False and now it works!! Yippieh!! Thank you sooooo much!!!

Comment: I have still one problem left :(  After running the code there is always one word instance that keeps running (I saw it fortuitously when opened tthe task manager)

Comment: Maybe have the task manager open and at the same time, go through the code step by step to see at what line the new instance appears. that can help us troubleshoot it.